# How to save has_many relation in Ruby on Rails using Devise gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

**User Model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tenant, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**Tenant Model**

```
class Tenant < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :users
end
```

**Controller**

```
class Accounts::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
```

Using build_

```
def create
    @tenant = Tenant.new
    @user = @tenant.build_user(params)
    @tenant.save
end
```

Using Model

```
def create
    @tenant = Tenant.new
    @user = User.build(params)
    @tenant.save
end
```

**SQL:**

- Foreign key is added.

**Working**

- Able to add User model data separately.
- Able to add tenant model data separately.

**Not working**

- Not able to map id from the tenant table to the user table's tenant_id.
  I tried many possibilities, but not working. Kindly guide me.

**DB Screenshot**
[image]

**Note:*

I am using Devise Gem.

Comment: If I can remember correctly should be the model where `belongs_to` is declared that has the `build` method, in this case should be `@user = User.new; @user.build_tenant(....;` But seems you aren't getting any error, so maybe I'm wrong. But you can try manually in Rails console.

Comment: I don't think build saves the user to the database,  try create instead.  Also in the second case you show you have to actually add the user to the tenant object before saving the tenant.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `build_` is created for the model belonging to.

**For example you can do:**

```
Loading development environment (Rails 5.2.1)
2.4.1 :001 > user = User.new(name:'James Kirk')
 => #<User id: nil, name: "James Kirk", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, tenant_id: nil> 
2.4.1 :002 > user.build_tenant(name:'Enterprise')
 => #<Tenant id: nil, name: "Enterprise", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.4.1 :003 > user.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Tenant Create (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "tenants" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["name", "Enterprise"], ["created_at", "2018-12-30 15:05:52.531519"], ["updated_at", "2018-12-30 15:05:52.531519"]]
  User Create (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at", "tenant_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "James Kirk"], ["created_at", "2018-12-30 15:05:52.534295"], ["updated_at", "2018-12-30 15:05:52.534295"], ["tenant_id", 2]]
   (1.3ms)  commit transaction
 => true
```

The above saves the tenant then passes the id to the user and saves the user.

**But you can not:**

```
2.4.1 :004 > tenant = Tenant.new(name:'Hazzard')
 => #<Tenant id: nil, name: "Hazzard", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.4.1 :005 > tenant.build_user(name:'Uncle Jesse')
NoMethodError: undefined method `build_user' for #<Tenant:0x007ff2bbd9b650>
```

---

**Option for your workflow:**
Save the `Tenant` instance before, get the `id` then save the `User` instance:

```
2.4.1 :009 > tenant = Tenant.new(name:'Hazzard')
 => #<Tenant id: nil, name: "Hazzard", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.4.1 :010 > tenant.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Tenant Create (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "tenants" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["name", "Hazzard"], ["created_at", "2018-12-30 15:12:36.122931"], ["updated_at", "2018-12-30 15:12:36.122931"]]
   (1.7ms)  commit transaction
 => true 
2.4.1 :011 > user = User.new(name:'Uncle Jesse', tenant_id: tenant.id)
 => #<User id: nil, name: "Uncle Jesse", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, tenant_id: 4> 
2.4.1 :012 > user.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Tenant Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "tenants".* FROM "tenants" WHERE "tenants"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Create (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at", "tenant_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "Uncle Jesse"], ["created_at", "2018-12-30 15:12:52.119957"], ["updated_at", "2018-12-30 15:12:52.119957"], ["tenant_id", 4]]
   (0.9ms)  commit transaction
 => true
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. however, your solution 1 is not correct because User belong to tenant so I can't user tenant after user.  your second solution may work but I am getting `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` and working on it

Comment: The first solution is "provided" by Rails itself when you need to create both user and its tenant at the same time. You can see that calling just `user.save` Rails first creates the `Tenant` then creates the `User` (read the logs I posted). That's because user requires `tenant_id`. To understand why you are getting the error, post the complete log, showing params.

Comment: But solution 1 is not saving the user table. It is saving only tenant table.

Comment: Yes it saves also `User`(`user.save`), check the log: `User Create (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("name", ..., "tenant_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "James Kirk"], ..., ["tenant_id", 2]]`. I suggest you try what I did manually in Rails console (launch it by `rails c` in terminal).

Comment: You are correct.  I guess, there is an issue with devise gem (for authentication).

Answer (score 1):

As per the description mentioned in the post, it seems like the reference of tenant is not saving in the users table.

Since tenant is having a has_many relationship with users, thus something like menioned below can make it to work:

```
def create
  @tenant = Tenant.find(params[:id])
  @user = @tenant.users.build(params)
  @user.save
end
```

Note: the params will be having the attributes of user model, whereas you will be passing the id of the tenant already saved in the database to reference it in user table.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Tenant.find(params[:id] will not work since I am creating user & tenant on same call.

Comment: Since you want to create tenant and user on the same call, then you can use the concept of nested attributes thus using Rails way of handling the associated data to be saved. Updated the answer as well for reference of it